# How to use trademark symbol in cloudinary

Tags: encoding, special-characters, cloudinary

How to use trademark symbol(TM) while generating image in cloudinary?
I'm double encoding special character. Registered and copy right symbol works fine, but trademark symbol is displayed as question mark (?)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do or how it is failing.  Show us your code, the expected output, and the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%E2%84%A2`, as explained here:
http://support.cloudinary.com/entries/34267121-How-to-use-tm-symbol-#view-post-24790211.
You should also make sure the font you're using supports that character.